# Scalable way to import images from payment-icons library into Angular

Tags: angular, svg, webpack

I am trying to use `payment-icons` library in angular. While the suggested import way:

```
import visa from 'payment-icons/min/flat/visa.svg';
```

does work, it is not scalable - I end up having a bunch of individual icons imports and a corresponding property for each and every icon my site supports. Also, I have a scenario, where I conditionally show the images depending on which cards are supported for specific transactions, so there is no reason I would even need a property:

Is there a more scalable way of lazy importing those images?

**component.ts**

```
import visa from 'payment-icons/min/flat/visa.svg';
import mastercard from 'payment-icons/min/flat/mastercard.svg';
import maestro from 'payment-icons/min/flat/maestro.svg';
import amex from 'payment-icons/min/flat/amex.svg';

// regardless of whether you make it a collection or an array
// this is horrible:

visa = visa;
mastercard = mastercard
maestro = maestro
amex = amex
```

(and then `<img [attr.src]="visa" alt="Visa"/>`)

Edit:

Actually, even though this method does work in the browser, it doesn't compile for production, `Cannot find module 'payment-icons/min/flat/mastercard.svg'` when `ng build --prod`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dumb component that use a service, and a input parameter

```
<my-svg [name]="credit-card"> <\my-svg>
```

In your service, create a array containing references to all your svg, want to use in project.

In your dumb component, you can resolve your svg name you get from input and resolve by using a method from your service that takes name of svg file as parameter and filter our array and return a reference or something that is able to bind to our img src property.

Dumb Component

```
<div class="my-svg">
<img [src]="imgSrc" />
</div>
```

I hope that can help to maintain scalability. For lazy loading images you can try with [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to solve it using angular.json assets definition to copy images though.
BTW, lazy loading won't work since I have al the card icons visible right away at once.